# Python3: Calling a function within a function to another function, how?

Tags: python, function, higher-order-functions

Here's a code sample

```
import random
def randomNum():
    i = random.randint(1,10)
    return i
```

this is just to add context

what's below is where the issue is at

```
def function1():
    randomNum()
    r = randomNum()
    if r = 2:
        #do something
        def function2():
            return True
```

this is the function 2 within the function 1, and which I want to call on function 3

```
def function3():
    #some code
    function = function2()
    if function == True:  #this last 2 lines is what i'm trying to achieve
        #do something
```

suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `function1` returns `None`, but it should return `function2`. In `function3` just check that `if function is not None:`
So, something like:

```
In [1]: import random
   ...: def randomNum():
   ...:     i = random.randint(1,4)
   ...:     return i
   ...:
   ...: def function1():
   ...:     randomNum()
   ...:     r = randomNum()
   ...:     print(r)
   ...:     if r == 2:
   ...:         #do something
   ...:         def function2():
   ...:             return True
   ...:         return function2
   ...:
   ...: def function3():
   ...:     function = function1()
   ...:     if function is not None:
   ...:         print("Did stuff")
   ...:     else:
   ...:        print("didn't do stuff")
   ...:
```

In action:

```
In [2]: function3()
4
didn't do stuff

In [3]: function3()
1
didn't do stuff

In [4]: function3()
3
didn't do stuff

In [5]: function3()
4
didn't do stuff

In [6]: function3()
3
didn't do stuff

In [7]: function3()
2
Did stuff

In [8]: function3()
4
didn't do stuff

In [9]: function3()
2
Did stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked beautifully.

I changed this line: `return function2` to  `function2()`

Comment: it's working because simply calling function2() returns true, so no need for an extra return statement

Comment: @T.Galisnky perhaps what I should say is that then it makes defining `function2` in `function1` unnecessary,